# Refactoring following lines of code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

```
- if clean_book_intro_component(:literary_works).present?
  %h2 Other Books Related to #{@book.title}
  %p.fact-text
    = clean_book_intro_component(:literary_works)
```

Can above code written by calling `clean_book_intro_component(:literary_works)` only once?

Implementation of `clean_book_intro_component`

```
def clean_book_intro_component(component)
  sanitize @book.intro.send(component), tags: %w(span b i p a), attributes: %w(id class style href)
end
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid calling `clean_book_intro_component(:literary_works)` twice? Is it an expensive method?

Comment: @spickermann: no, just wondering if there is better way to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- clean_book_intro_component(:literary_works).tap do |cbic|
  - if cbic.present?
    %h2 Other Books Related to #{@book.title}
    %p.fact-text
      = cbic
```

maybe I got haml wrong, but the idea is to use `tap` instead of explicitly saving the result of the call

Comment: Nice!  I was trying to post similar answer, but could not get indentation right and kept getting error.

Comment: This is cool, are there any performance caveat for using tap over calling method two times?

Answer (score 1):

Assigning variables in view is generally not recommended. However, in this case you can use an inline assignment which is generally accepted (as long as you keep the usage scoped within the context of the condition block):

```
if (intro = clean_book_intro_component(:literary_works)).present?
  %h2 Other Books Related to #{@book.title}
  %p.fact-text
    = intro
```

Another solution is to memoize the value inside the function.

```
def clean_book_intro_component(component)
  @component ||= {}
  @component[component] ||= sanitize @book.intro.send(component), tags: %w(span b i p a), attributes: %w(id class style href)
end
```

However, this will cause the interpreter to retain the data as long as there is a reference to the instance. Therefore, this is recommended only in very particular cases where the execution is expensive and/or the data to be memoized is limited.

Moreover, it requires some extra complications if the helper accepts parameters. In fact, you will end up memoizing an amount of data which is linear with the possible input of the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just save the result of `clean_book_intro_component(:literary_works)` in a variable and then use that variable instead of invoking the function.

Comment: Hmm.. that I know, I'm just wondering if there is any better way to do it.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti: Didn't realize it was a view. I'm not really familiar with RoR or Ruby. Still think it's fine, but I guess it should really be in the underlying model instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the view into a partial and call the partial on a collection. If the collection is empty nothing is rendered. Something like:

```
# a related_books partial
%h2 Other Books Related to #{@book.title}
  %p.fact-text
    = related_books


# in the calling view
= render partial: related_books, collection: [clean_book_intro_component(:literary_works)]
```

See the Rails Guide about [rendering collections](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections).